# zend autoloader cannot find file

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-autoloader

i want to add Uploader class into my zend application

in library folder i add uploder.php and inside the Uploder.php i start class with 
class Amjad_Uploder {...}

in application.ini i add the following lines

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

appnamespace= "Application"

autoloaderNamespaces[] ="Amjad_"

in controller i call the class by writing

$uploder=new Amjad_Uploder();

i still have these errors

Warning: include_once(Amjad\Uploader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\amjad\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 134

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Amjad\Uploader.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\wamp\www\amjad\application/../library;C:\wamp\www\amjad/library;.;c:\php\includes;D:\Zend Library\') in C:\wamp\www\amjad\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 134

Fatal error: Class 'Amjad_Uploader' not found in C:\wamp\www\amjad\application\modules\admin\controllers\scincetificController.php on line 34

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that in the `library` folder, you need to create a folder called `Amjad` and place `Uploder.php` in there.  It sounds like you put `Uploder.php` directly in `library`.

Answer (score -2):

I always thought that I should have in the application.ini

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] ="Amjad"
```

and not

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] ="Amjad_"
```